# How much cancer medicine can I bring to Canada for a 2-week visit?

Tags: canada, air-canada, tsa-precheck

I’m a person with health issues and need to take medication daily.

---

I am traveling to Canada for two weeks and need to bring my cancer meds. Plus I take calcium tablets everyday. My injection appointment is during the vacation, but I’m planning to bring 2 with me just in case. I'm also bringing 4 boxes of calcium tablets and my others 2 femara and a few vitamins and medication that I regularly take.

How much can I bring? I have the prescriptions and everything prepared. I tend to misplace things that's why I am planning to bring too much, will it be an issue?

Comment: I edited in a later question by OP which did explain what kind of medication.

Answer (score 2):

You can bring medicine for two weeks and some more for emergency. Keep the prescription, in case it is asked.

Comment: This may depend on what type of medicine the OP needs. See [Travelling into and out of Canada with prescription medications](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/health-concerns/controlled-substances-precursor-chemicals/controlled-substances/compliance-monitoring/travelling-into-and-out-of-canada-with-prescription-medication-containing-controlled-substances.html)

Comment: Some more can be double for a short visit, depending on the way the medication is packed and how essential it is for the person.